# Fast multi-string replacement

Tags: c#, regex

I need to perform multi string replacement. I have a string where several parts need to be changed according to substitution map.

All replacement must be done in one action - it means if "`a`" should be replaced with "`b`" and also "`b`" must be replaced with "`c`" and input string is "`abc`", the result will be "`bcc`"
I have a sollution based on building regex and then replacing all matches. I wrote it some time ago, now I'm refactoring the code and not so satisfied with it. Is there better (faster, simplier) sollution?

This is what I have:

```
public static string Replace(string s, Dictionary<string, string> substitutions)
{
    string pattern = "";
    int i = 0;
    foreach (string ch in substitutions.Keys)
    {
        if (i == 0)
           pattern += "(" + Regex.Escape(ch) + ")";
        else
           pattern += "|(" + Regex.Escape(ch) + ")";
        i++;
     }

     var r = new Regex(pattern);
     var parts = r.Split(s);

     string ret = "";
     foreach (string part in parts)
     {
         if (part.Length == 1 && substitutions.ContainsKey(part[0].ToString()))
         {
             ret += substitutions[part[0].ToString()];
         }
         else
         {
             ret += part;
         }
      }
      return ret;
}
```

And test case:

```
 var test = "test aabbcc";
 var output = Replace(test, new Dictionary<string, string>{{"a","b"},{"b","y"}});
 Assert.That(output=="test bbyycc");
```

Comment: Never use "+" on strings unless it is to add a few strings (less than 4 strings) ... use StringBuilder instead !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can replace all this with

```
var r = new Regex(string.Join("|", substitutions.Keys.Select(k => "(" + k + ")")));     
return r.Replace(s, m => substitutions[m.Value]);
```

The key things are making use of the [`string.Join`](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx&ei=wfENU-CKJYXBtAbm-IHABg&usg=AFQjCNEg-KC113dlZ7I1pkrZT_FG0A0Hvg&sig2=kTWKRU66kNLC3UITxz-XNg&bvm=bv.61965928,d.Yms) method rather than implementing it yourself, and making use of this [`Regex.Replace` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and delegates to do the replacement.

Comment: Nice, thank you. I'm just wondering if there is a totally different approach. Yours uses linq and Regex.Replace but the main idea remains.